# C++ small bank program using a class

Tags: c++

I want to create a bank program in C++ that will store customer information (maybe in a text file or some sort) like:

```
name
account type
account number
account balance
deposit and withdraw functions
edit account
delete account
show all account.
```

---

```
Class bankAccounts
{
   private:
string customerName
char accType
int accountNo
double accBalance
   public:
bankAccounts()
~bankAccounts()
displayAccount()
depositAccount()
withdrawAccount()
deleteAccount()
showAccounts()
```

how would i use the constructor? maybe to set the balance and accountnum to 0. how could i do this and also how would i implement other functions?

Comment: Steps to success: 1. [Learn how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 2. Learn how classes work in C++, including constructors/destructors, inheritance, polymorphism, and all related stuff. 3. Think. **Write code**. If it doesn't work, rewrite or ask a **specific question** here on Stack Overflow. **Note** that I'm not being sarcastic here but rather helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how. Create a [Parameterized Constructor](http://forgetcode.com/Cpp/667-Parameterized-Constructor) and pass the values you want to be assigned to the object as arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class bankAccounts
{
private:
    std::string customerName;
    char accType;
    int accountNo;
    double accBalance;

public:
    bankAccounts();

    bankAccounts(std::string cn ,char act, int acno, double accB) //Parameterized constructor
    {
        customerName =cn;
        accType=act;
        accountNo=acno;
        accBalance=accB;
    }

    //Implement your functions inside/ outside the class

    // displayAccount();
    // depositAccount();
    // withdrawAccount();
    // deleteAccount();
    // showAccounts();

};


int main()
{
    std::string customerName;
    char accType;
    int accountNo;
    double accBalance;
    std::cin>>customerName>>accType>>accountNo>>accBalance;//get your data
    bankAccounts B(customerName, accType, accountNo, accBalance);
    //object B has all attributes you wanted

    //Enjoy :)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Won't compile, sorry.

Comment: Wasn't meant to. Just gave an overview. Hold on

Comment: I do and I will but only if your program compiles. As it stands, it doesn't. Function declarations without a return type are only allowed in < C99 and not at all in C++. And why use `string` but `std::cin`? The namespace specifier annoys me.

Comment: Yes done. I'm sorry I'm currently not working with my editor :P

Comment: Looks OK now but rather use an initializer list as common in C++.

Comment: 'initializer list`? I'm sorry i dont understand

Comment: Yes, but it shows the OP and any subsequent reader bad habits. I wouldn't say that a fine program's only requirement is to compile and work but also to be readable and maintainable.

Comment: why use std::string if i have included it in my program #include <string>. surely there is no need to use std::string. it confuses me everytime i see it.

Comment: Besides, the C++ string is a part of the std namespace

Comment: still doesnt compile. i am using the header file with my class, cpp file for implementation and a main. ive included the header file in my main and also include header file in the cpp file.